# Do PhoneGap apps reset themselves on app update?

Tags: iphone, html, cordova, local-storage

I am developing a PhoneGap app for iOS, and future app updates are part of the plan.
Sometimes, updates are not backwards-compatible and I am afraid that the app will still run on an outdated cache/session despite the update.

**After the user updates their PhoneGap app:**

- Will they still see the last page they opened before updating?
- Will the browser cache (i.e. outdated HTML/JS/CSS files) be reset?
- Will old localStorage data still be there?
- What about the behaviour on Android and BlackBerry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your localStorage will stay put, everything else will go be replaced and the app will restart fresh.

Do some tests, if you make a build and compile upload to your phone then change some things recompile and upload you'll see that it has updated, but your localStorage is stil there.

hope that helps!

Comment: That helped a lot. I just wish this behaviour was officially documented (if it isn't already).

Thanks!

Comment: awesome, it is a bit.. it's a bit lacking as far as if it will stay around. but best bet with anything like that is to just test! :)

Answer (score 0):

Watch out! There is a serious bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-347